# strtotime with GET variable gives wrong day

Tags: php

```
$time = strtotime($_GET['Datum']);
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", $time);
```

The above snippet gives me the wrong date.

Actually it always returns the current date.

I submit the date via a text field and it formatted like this: "dd-mm-yyyy". But for example, if I enter 20.02.2014 it returns 2014-02-22.

Comment: That's because your date functions says you want Y-m-d, which means 2014-02-22. If you want the format you like you need to say date("d.m.Y"); And what does $_GET['Datum'] do? Do you retrieve a date from your url or something?

Comment: @berentrom the thing you missed is his day is 20 not 22 so its chaning the day

Comment: [I can't reproduce that](http://3v4l.org/bJfUX)

Comment: @prix I know, I was referring to his format.

Comment: What does $time output?

Comment: [Same here, can't reproduce.](https://eval.in/104508) So perhaps you have something wrong with your `$_GET['Datum']` data

Comment: @rakeshjain: [`dd [.\t-] mm [.-] YY` is a valid format for `strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `$_GET['Datum']` does NOT contain what you think it contains... Debug that.

Comment: please share complete code to give a better context

Comment: I can't reproduce it as well, `$_GET['Datum'] = '20-02-2014'; echo $time = strtotime($_GET['Datum']); echo '<br>'; echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d", $time); echo '<br>';`